# How to validate php dropdown menu populated from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a Form select dropdown field that populates from DB table.

As i have validated other fields against empty value, special chars, email and number formats etc, i want to also be able to validate the select dropdown field against Non-selection by user.

This is my code

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Center</label>

        <?php 
             echo "<select class='form-control' name='center_name'>";
             $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT center_name FROM 
             center");

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                   unset($center_name);
                   $center_name = $row['center_name']; 

                   echo '<option 
                   value="'.$center_name.'">'.$center_name.'</option>';

             }

         echo "</select>";
    ?>                               
</div>
```

The code below is what i already ran but didn't work.

```
if (!isset($_POST["center_name"])) {
            $centerError = "Select your center ";
            }else{
                $center_name = check_input($_POST["center_name"]);//trim 
and stripslashes function  
            }
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". What did you expect vs what happened? Also, you should escape for html the select's options you pickup from the database before outputting them to the form.

Comment: I expected that if selection is not made from the dropdown, an error message should display. such as "You have not selected center"

Answer (score 1):

In this example you see how you can detect if the page has been requeste with a POST vs a GET which would happen when not submitting the form.

Then on the top, if it is a `POST`, you do the checkings and if invalid you set an error message.

Afterwards you render the html, and conditionally you show or not the error message.

The `print_r()` on the top lets you peek the `$_POST` array's contents.

**File name: process-select.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
$action = '';
$center_name = '';
$center_name_error = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'):
    $action = 'posting';
    $center_name = isset($_POST["center_name"]) ? $_POST["center_name"] : '';        
    if(empty($center_name)){
        $center_name_error = "Please select an option";
    }

endif;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Select example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Select example submitted to php</h1>
<form method="post" action="process-select.php">
    <select name="center_name">
        <option value="" <?php echo empty($center_name)? 'selected' : '' ?>></option>
        <option value="Option 1" <?php echo $center_name === 'Option 1'? 'selected' : '' ?>>Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2" <?php echo $center_name === 'Option 2'? 'selected' : '' ?>>Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3" <?php echo $center_name === 'Option 3'? 'selected' : '' ?>>Option 3</option>
        <option value="Option 4" <?php echo $center_name === 'Option 4'? 'selected' : '' ?>>Option 4</option>
        <option value="Option 5" <?php echo $center_name === 'Option 5'? 'selected' : '' ?>>Option 5</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <?php if($action === 'posting' && !empty($center_name_error)): ?>
        <p><?php echo $center_name_error ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the form field will still be submitted to the server !isset wont work here.

Use

```
if (empty($_POST["center_name"]))
```

instead of

```
if (!isset($_POST["center_name"]))
```